# data lake job fails when job preparation time exceeds 25 mins

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am processing an input file set of approximately 4000 csv files in Data Lake, the job fails with script compile error when job preparation time exceeds 25 mins

we have a requirement to bulk process beyond 4000 csv files, I have heard Microsoft has a solution in preview to process input file set size as large as 30,000 files

Answer (score 2):

This is currently an [opt-in preview feature](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2017/2017_03_09/USQL_Release_Notes_2017_03_09.md).  Please use the "contact us" section at this link to contact the ADLA support team.

**Input File Set scales orders of magnitudes better (requires opt-in)**
https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2017/2017_03_09/USQL_Release_Notes_2017_03_09.md

As an *alternative*, you might consider Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Polybase for importing and storing flat files which would be super fast.  ADLA can then connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse using [federated tables](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2016/06/17/setup-azure-data-lake-analytics-federated-u-sql-queries-to-azure-sql-database.aspx).  This gives you the ability to "query data where it lives" and leans towards the idea of a logical data lake, which uses the two products, Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA).  The trade-off is a more complex architecture / setup but Polybase is optimised for fast flat-file import.  Just an idea.

**NB** I do not work for Microsoft, I'm just copying and pasting the links : )